# JSF Not Using Converter

Tags: java, jsf, converters

I have a selectManyCheckbox that has a converter declared in it. The problem is that the converter is called but that value from the converter is not being used instead the toString method is of the object. Any thoughts?

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox valuePassThru="frue">
 <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.user.types}"/>
 <f:converter converterId="com.converters.UserTypeConverter"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I have dont it the other way with the converter in the selectManyCheckbox but with the same outcome.

Comment: I don't think there is any `valuePassThru` attribute. Do you have the code for the converter?

Comment: @Bhesh: I recognize this as an ADF-faces specific attribute. Apparently the OP simplified the question with replacing `<af:selectManyCheckbox>` by `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` to make it more accessible to JSF developers who are not familiar with ADF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `converter` as attribute to `selectManyCheckbox`?

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox converter="com.converters.UserTypeConverter">
 <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.user.types}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Also keep in mind that the converter only applies on the input value, not on the input label.

Comment: That really shouldn't make any difference, but your point about the label versus value is very valid.

Comment: @BalusC I have seen quite some things that shouldn't have made any difference. In my experience the suggested was less error prone in some implementations. Think it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not related to the actual bug, but you have an error in valuePassThru="**frue**".